# GORM Association Append worked on MySQL but gives an error on SQLite

Tags: sqlite, go-gorm

Because of various reasons, I have to change my database to SQLite after I finished creating my server. As I was testing out my server after switching to SQLite, an `Association().Append()` is now throwing a

> ambiguous column name: id

error. Here's what my code looks like:

```
func (*AccountServer) UpdateAccountOwnedEdgeDevice(ctx context.Context, req *pb.UpdateAccountOwnedEdgeDeviceRequest) (*pb.UpdateAccountOwnedEdgeDeviceResponse, error) {
    var account models.Account

    toInsertEdgeDevice := &models.EdgeDeviceInfo{
        ID:          req.EdgeDevice.Id,
        Name:        req.EdgeDevice.Name,
        Description: req.EdgeDevice.Description,
    }

    res := cmmHelpers.GetDB().First(&account, "id = ?", req.Id)

    if res.RowsAffected == 0 {
        return nil, errors.New("accounts not found")
    }

    err := res.Association("OwnedEdgeDevices").Append(
        toInsertEdgeDevice,
    )

    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return &pb.UpdateAccountOwnedEdgeDeviceResponse{
        Success: true,
    }, nil
}
```

GORM is showing this query as well:

> UPDATE `accounts` SET `updated_at`="2023-11-29 14:30:20.428" FROM
> `accounts` WHERE id = "7e8c7eba-a676-4743-8e28-75d02f105555" AND
> `accounts`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND `id` =
> "7e8c7eba-a676-4743-8e28-75d02f105555"

I just realized that another API endpoint related to `account` is throwing an error as well. Here's what the model for `account` looks like:

```
type Account struct {
    gorm.Model
    ID                 string           `gorm:"primarykey; size:40;"`
    FirstName          string           `json:"first_name"`
    LastName           string           `json:"last_name"`
    UserName           string           `gorm:"unique; not null" json:"user_name"`
    Password           string           `gorm:"column:password"`
    Email              *string          `binding:"required" json:"email"`
    OwnedEdgeDevices   []EdgeDeviceInfo `gorm:"many2many:user_owned_edge_devices;" json:"owned_edge_devices"`
    NeedPasswordChange bool             `gorm:"default:false;" json:"need_password_change"`
}
```

And here's the model that I want to associate with it:

```
type EdgeDeviceInfo struct {
    gorm.Model
    ID          string  `gorm:"primarykey; size:40;"`
    Name        string `gorm:"not null" json:"name"`
    Description string  `json:"description"`
    Status      bool    `gorm:"default:false; column:statusz"`
    APIKey      string  `json:"api_key"`
    Passcode    string  `gorm:"default:0000"`
}
```